# Reattach modified entity with nested child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm using EF 6.1

**Model**

I have entries, containing an user which itself contains a city. The entry also has a supplier.
I retrieve my entries with .AsNoTracking():

```
 return dbContext.Set<entry>()
            .Include(x => x.user.city)
            .Include(x => x.supplier).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

I have even more properties but they are all similar.

**View**

The user sees one entry and can change all member variables of all properties. He can change the entry id (not the PrimaryKey). He can change the user's last name. He can change the city's name or zip code. And so on...

**Problem**

Think about this example:

entry: id = 123

user: first_name = "Foo", last_name = "Bar"

city: name = "FooCity", zip_code = "4711"

The user sees this. He can now change the first_name to "Peter" and click save. Then I'm doing this:

```
dbContext.Set<entry>().Add(modifiedAndNotTrackedEntry);
dbContext.Entry(modifiedAndNotTrackedEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But then EF duplicates all child entites. So in the DB I have a new user, which might be what I want if the user does not yet exist. But this user points to a new city altough the city wasn't changed. Furthermore the supplier now exists two times in the database.

**Why `AsNoTracking()`**

I have used `AsNoTracking()` because the user sees the real entity. If he changes something it directly affects all entities: Setting first_name to "Peter" all entries which had "Foo" "Bar" as user, then have "Peter" "Bar" as user. But only the modified entity should have this change. I think that happens because I directly modify the member variable of the "real" entity in the context.

**Question**

How can I reattach a modified entity without recreating existing child entities.

OR

How can I achieve what I want without using `AsNoTracking()`

Comment: Hmm, so your problem is basically, that the navigation properties of your modified object are unknown (detached) and when the object is saved, they are treated as new entries. Do you use foreign key properties in your data model?

Comment: I tried both. At the moment I have foreign key properties.

Comment: Can you explicitely attach the related entities or is the code to generic for that? I mean like `db.Entry(modifiedAndNotTrackedEntry).Reference(x => x.user).EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged` or `db.Entry(modifiedAndNotTrackedEntry.user).State = EntityState.Unchanged`, same for other properties.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I have too many properties and then I have to check every property if it is changed.

Comment: Set<>.Add() will add all child properties to their corresponsing sets also. either use another function to add the object to its set again, remove .AsNoTracking() so you are not required to add it again, or remove the child objects from the object beforehand/from the context afterwards. I don't see any other solution.

Comment: Why is this so difficult and ugly? Is this such a crazy thing I'm doing? I can't believe I'm the only one doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Setting first_name to "Peter" all entries which had "Foo" "Bar" as user, then have "Peter" "Bar" as user.'

Comment: An entry has a user and a user has a string first_name and a string last_name. Changing one of the member variables changes it for all entities using this child entity. So when SaveChanges() is called the user "Foo" "Bar" is now "Peter" "Bar" in the DB. It does no create a new user if I change the member variables.

Comment: If I have 3 entries pointing to the child entity "Foo" Bar" and I change the first_name to "Peter" they still all point to this child entity. But this entity has a different content now.

Comment: Maybe you should just use a different context instance for the data you want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I´m trying same thing as you, i´m not sure to understand quite well your reasson thought, but probably this document will help you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx

Also, i´m almost sure that you don´t need to execute .Add() in your example, that will result in new record most of the cases, or in "Unchanged" if apply.

I can achieve to attach same entity with new values just by attaching and applying state = modified, still researching how to re-attach related properties (my worst problem is the 1toN relationship)

Check under "Attaching an existing entity to the context", probably it leads you a solution.

I´m also researching an interesting post here in code project:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33088/Reattaching-Entity-Graphs-with-the-Entity-Framewor

It seems this guy invented an extension to re-attach node graphs on entity framework, like "here you have the missing feature from EF." I´ll give it a try.

Regards.